# Rest API with oauth2 work just in browser, error in python

Tags: python, rest, api, oauth-2.0

i can access a API by browser requesting URL?access_token=jdjdfjhdjkdhf for example, and open a json in browser with datas, so 200 OK

The api is Oauth2.0

When i try open this same API in python, i'm receveing a 401 error, i check the readers but can't access, code below

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.myRUL/web_api/auth' #url de obtenção token

consumer_key = 'MYCONSUMERKEY'
consumer_secret = 'MYSECRET'
code = 'MYCODE'

payload = {'consumer_key' : consumer_key,'consumer_secret' : consumer_secret,'code' : code}
response = requests.post(url, json=payload)
response = response.json()
print(response)
```

At this point I can receive a access_token into a json in python, with a 200OK code, so I try access data with my ne access_token

Something like that, just a example json with no real datas:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 OK
{
    code: 201,
    message: "Created tokens",
    access_token: "abc96fb7b1defd2496b9a9d81071fa12319b12306465e057d0ebca9bd9ab19",
    refresh_token: "bbc96fb7b1defd2496b9a9d81071fa12319b12306465e057d0ebca9bd9ab19",
    date_expiration_access_token: "2016-08-12 14:35:14",
    date_expiration_refresh_token: "2016-09-11 11:35:14",
    date_activated: "2016-08-12 11:35:14",
    store_id: "123123"
}
```

And than, finally when i try acceses the api with my access_token

```
url_orders = 'myURL/web_api/orders' #url de consulta
headers  = {"Accept": "application/json"}
pay = {'access_token': response['access_token']}

print(requests.get(url_orders, json=pay))
```

So i receive a error 401

What I'm doing wrong

Thank you

Comment: Do you need to pass `headers` as well? `requests.get(url_orders, headers=headers, json=pay)`? And/or should it also be a POST request like the first one? It would be easier if you provided the actual url for testing.

Comment: Hi @G_M, thanks for the help, acctualy i call my uri manually, cause i cant solve the issue with requests. I dump my URI in requests and see the code `requests.post(url, json=payload)` are mount a wrong URI, the uri was `MYURL?b'{'consumer_key' : consumer_key,'consumer_secret' : consumer_secret,'code' : code}'` So i'm mount the URI manually!